# Meteor+React Error: Uncaught Invariant Violation: _registerComponent(...): Target container is not a DOM element

Tags: meteor, reactjs, meteor-react

I am looking at LevelUpTuts Meteor+React for everybody series. 
I am having " Uncaught Invariant Violation: _registerComponent(...): Target container is not a DOM element. " error but I don't know where the problem is.

```
client/Main.html
<head>
<title>myResolutions</title>
<meta charset="utf-8"/>
</head>

<body>
<div id="target-render"></div>
<script src="./App.js"></script
</body>
```

In my App.jsx

```
client/App.jsx
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

class App extends React.Component{
render() {
    return (
        <h1> Hello World </h1>
    )
}
}

if(Meteor.isClient){
Meteor.startup(function(){
    ReactDOM.render(<App />,document.getElementById("render-target"));
});
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like in the html you have the id as "target-render", and in the javascript you have the id as "render-target".  They need to match.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the problem is coming from this line:

It shouldn't be here.

and I highly recommend you to use official Meteor tutorials instead of anything else:
https://www.meteor.com/tutorials/react/creating-an-app

Answer (score 0):

First of, you need to import `Meteor`, `import { Meteor } from 'meteor/meteor';` and then you don't need to include `<script src="./App.js"></script>` in your html. Note you have a typo on that line, you didn't properly close the script tag